# Where to upload JS file which can be refer in Jsfiddle like CDN but for free

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have upladed 1 file on githut

```
https://github.com/alpesh-jikadra/Resources/blob/master/js/hello.js
```

So that I can refer it in my `https://jsfiddle.net/6e7vp9p7/6/`,

but as you all know I can not use js uploaded on github as CDN server because I am getting following error.

*Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/alpesh-jikadra/Resources/blob/master/js/hello.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type*

**So my question is**

where should I upload this js file , so that I can refer it in my JsFiddle demo.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e7vp9p7/6/)

Thanks

Comment: Please read the Help Center and read up on how to ask a question.

Comment: try plunkr instead. you can have as many files as you want.

Comment: upload to github then reference it

Comment: @JoeWarner Git hub does not allow to refer JS as CDN server

Comment: yeah but https://rawgit.com/

Comment: I am not getting why I got down vote, because question is very simple, and I got immediate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your own server, you could host the file there. If you create a GitHub project or maybe a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), you can use [Raw Git](https://rawgit.com/).

Just grab the URL for your file in your GitHub project and copy the Prod or Dev link. Raw Git wraps your file in the appropriate headers for AJAX calls.

---

**Update:** If you put your project on GitHub, and publish it to npm; you can access it via the [jsDelivr CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/).